# mysql: unknown option '--includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/'

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to login to mysql through terminal, but getting error when i type

```
mysql -u root
```

Error:

> mysql: unknown option '--includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/'

Help me: why  am I not able to login to mysql through terminal ?

in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
>
> includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

Comment: One has `!`, the other does not??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried login with the password:

```
mysql -u root -p<Password>
```

FYI: There is no space bettween `-p` and `password`

Comment: No. Actually i installed mysql with no password

Comment: For me it was the space between -p and password. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the --includedir option, MariaDB reads the mariadb.conf.d configuration files by default.